# Issues related to Flutter and Firebase

Tags: flutter

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPQ8R.png)

I am not able to load the pictures in the application which Firebase is storing other than Firebase images the app is loading it. I have stored the URL in Firebase of "www.unsplash.com" manually it is showing me the image there is no logical error in the code

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur when there are issues with loading or displaying images from Firebase storage or when there are problems with network connectivity.

1. Check your internet connection.This error may occur if the device is not connected to the internet or if the connection is too slow. If using emulator, try real device.
2. Double-check your Firebase configuration in your Flutter project. Make sure you have properly initialized Firebase in your **main.dart** or equivalent file using **Firebase.initializeApp()**.
3. Review your Firebase Storage security rules to ensure make the rules public. If the rules are too restrictive, it may lead to the error.

Firestore Public Rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Storage Public Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

4. If you are using direct URLs to access the images, verify that the URLs are correct and accessible. Test the URLs in a browser to check if the images can be loaded outside of your Flutter app.
5. Wrap the code with a try-catch block where you are fetching or displaying images from Firebase.